# Beginner Adobe Acrobat Pro Javascript Question

Tags: javascript, adobe

First time using stackoverflow. I have just been tasked to generate PDF reports that come in a standardized form. There are a bunch of repetitive and tedious tasks that I have to do over hundreds of more or less identical forms.

The forms have an "Incident Number" in one of the cells in the form and in the cell to the right, there is a 5 digit number. I currently need to manually highlight this 5 digit number. I would like to automate this process across all the files that I need to process.

Is this done with action wizard or the Javascript function in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC?

I have no background in Javascript but have been using Chatgpt to help write code for me. The catch is the code isn't doing anything, or highlighting stuff in really weird ways, I used the code in a dummy file that simply has the word "hello" in it.

Here is ChatGPT's code for highlighting the incident number

```
// Get all form fields
var fields = this.getFieldObjects();

// Loop through all fields
for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
  var field = fields[i];

  // Check if the field is the "Incident Number" field
  if (field.name === "Incident Number") {

    // Get the value of the next field
    var nextField = fields[i + 1];
    var fieldValue = nextField.valueAsString;

    // Use regex to find the 5 digits in the field value
    var regex = /(\d{5})/;
    var match = regex.exec(fieldValue);

    // Check if a match was found
    if (match) {

      // Highlight the matched text
      var startIndex = match.index;
      var endIndex = match.index + match[0].length;
      nextField.selectText(startIndex, endIndex);
      nextField.highlight = color.yellow; // Change color as per your requirement
    }
  }
}
```

Here's ChatGPT's code for highlighting the word Hello

```
// Get all page objects
var pages = this.getAnnots();

// Loop through all pages
for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
  var page = pages[i];

  // Get all text fields on the page
  var fields = page.getAnnots({subtype: "Widget"});

  // Loop through all text fields
  for (var j = 0; j < fields.length; j++) {
    var field = fields[j];

    // Get the value of the text field
    var fieldValue = field.valueAsString;

    // Use regex to find the word "hello"
    var regex = /hello/gi; // "gi" flag for global case-insensitive search
    var match = regex.exec(fieldValue);

    // Check if a match was found
    while (match) {

      // Highlight the matched text
      var startIndex = match.index;
      var endIndex = match.index + match[0].length;
      field.setRichText(true);
      field.richValue = [{
        text: fieldValue.substring(startIndex, endIndex),
        textColor: color.black,
        fillColor: color.yellow // Change color as per your requirement
      }];

      // Find the next match
      match = regex.exec(fieldValue);
    }
  }
}
```

I guess the clarity I'm looking for is as follows

1. Is what I am wanting to achieve possible within Adobe Acrobat Javascript?
2. Where exactly am I inserting the code step by step- is it in action wizard or javascript
3. Is the code that chat GPT going to work?